# jQuery mobile - close panel on history back

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I have a jQuery mobile panel which slides in from the side, it works great.
But lets say you have a login page, that redirects to a main page with a panel. Now if the user opens the panel, and then clicks the back button, he expects the panel to close. But instead the browser navigates back to the login page.

I´ve tried adding something to the url:

```
window.location.hash = "panelOpen";
```

But that just messes up the jQuery mobile history state pattern. I´ve also tried to listen to the navigate event, and prevent it if a panel is open:

```
$(window).on('navigate', function (e, hans) {
     var panels = $('[data-role="panel"].ui-panel-open');
     if (panels&&panels.length>0) {
         e.preventDefault();
         e.stopPropagation();
         $('#' + panels[0].id).panel('close');
           return false;
         }
});
```

This kind of works, except that the url is changed, and I cannot grab the event that changes the url. Furthermore, it also messes up the jQuery mobile history pattern.

So how does people achieve this expected 'app-like' behaviour with a jQuery mobile panel; open panel > history back > close panel. And thats it.

Thanks alot!

Answer (score 1):

### Updated

Instead of retrieving current URL from jQuery Mobile's history, It is safer to retrieve it from `hashchange` event `event.originalEvent.newURL` and then pass it to `popstate` event to be `replaceState()` with that URL.

---

Instead of listening to `navigate`, listen to `popstate` which fires before. The trick here is *manipulate* both browser's history and jQuery Mobile's history by `replaceState()` and *reload* same page without *transition*.

```
var newUrl;
$(window).on("hashchange", function (e) {
    /* retrieve URL */
    newUrl = e.originalEvent.newURL;
}).on("popstate", function (e) {
    var direction = e.historyState.direction == "back" ? true : false,
        activePanel = $(".ui-panel-open").length > 0 ? true : false,
        url = newUrl,
        title = document.title;
    if (direction && activePanel) {
        $(".ui-panel-open").panel("close");
        $(".ui-header .ui-btn-active").removeClass("ui-btn-active");
        /* reload same page to maintain jQM's history */
        $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("change", url, {
            allowSamePageTransition: true
        });
        /* replace state to maintain browsers history */
        window.history.replaceState({}, title, url);
        /* prevent navigating into history */
        return false;
    }
});
```

This part is meant to maintain same transition used previously as `transition` is set to `none` when reloading same page.

```
$(document).on("pagebeforechange", function (e, data) {
    if (data.options && data.options.allowSamePageTransition) {
        data.options.transition = "none";
    } else {
        data.options.transition = $.mobile.defaultPageTransition;
    }
});
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/9wr1ascw/show/)** - **[Code](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/9wr1ascw/embedded/js/)**

Comment: Hi Omar, I have the same problem.. any change to get this to work for JQM 1.4.5?

Comment: @deblocker hi, I honestly don't it has been so long since I came near jQM. Can you start a new quetion, maybe I can help you :)

Answer (score 1):

I am a little bit late on the party, but i had recently the same requirements and i would like to share how i did it. So, i extended the requirement in the original question to `Panels`, `Popups` and `Pages`:

> ...an expected 'app-like' behaviour, history back > close
>   whaterver is open. And thats it.

In `.on("panelopen")`, `.on("popupafteropen")` and `.on("pagecontainershow")` i simply add another entry to the window history, by using the HTML5 API (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API) (I believe there is no need to use the JQM navigate browser quirks for that):

```
window.history.pushState({}, window.document.title, window.location.href);
```

After that, i'm using more or less Omar's function to intercept the `popstate` event:

```
$(window).on("popstate", function (e) {
  var pageId = $(":mobile-pagecontainer").pagecontainer("getActivePage").prop("id");
  var pageOpen = (pageId != "page-home");
  var panelOpen = $(".ui-panel-open").length > 0;
  var popupOpen = $(".ui-popup-active").length > 0;

  if(pageOpen) {
    $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("change", "#page-home", {reverse: true});
    return false;
  }
  if(panelOpen) {
    $(".ui-panel-open").panel("close");
    return false;
  }
  if(popupOpen) {
    $(".ui-popup-active .ui-popup").popup("close")
    return false;
  }
});
```

As you see, the is just only one level to the home-page, but this can be easily extended by using JQM history implementation to get the previous page:

```
var activeId = $.mobile.navigate.history.activeIndex;
var jqmHistory = $.mobile.navigate.history.stack; // array of pages
```

and use `pagecontainer` to change to the active entry - 1.

---

*As last note, this works well also by completely disabling the built-in JQM Ajax navigation system:*

```
/* Completely disable navigation for mobile app */
$.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
$.mobile.loadingMessage = false;
$.mobile.pushStateEnabled = false;
$.mobile.hashListeningEnabled = false;
$.mobile.changePage.defaults.changeHash = false;
$.mobile.popup.prototype.options.history = false;
```

*(Tested in Browser, on real Android and iOS devices)*