# Stop the back history, juste close panel

Tags: jquery-mobile, navigation, back

When I click the back button on the browser, my panel closes but the listener events brought me back to the previous page, I want in my function an element that closes the panel without me go back

```
$(window).on("navigate", function (event, data) {
  var direction = data.state.direction;
  if (direction == 'back') {
    $("#mypanel").panel("close");
  }
});
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25808411/1771795

Comment: What issues are facing with that code?

Comment: it works except on my first page, I lost focus, I have some items that are injected but I can't see. URL problem I think

Comment: No, it's not a URL problem. This solution doesn't work on first page, because you can't control user leaving your page. When user is on first page and hit "back", it will exit your website. Other pages are control via jQM history and `replaceState` in API history.

Comment: ahh it is binding but I understand the interest.
No way to fix it by adding an address when the panel opens ? For that is added to the story

Comment: Also I noticed that the script blocked popup external on multipages document, it will not open

Comment: True, I will be blocked as popup changes URL. I'll revise my code.