# jquery mobile- override back device button event

Tags: jquery-mobile

I want the back button to toggle div for example.
How I can override the device back button event action?

I tried

```
document.addEventListener('backbutton', function() {
  return false;
});
```

and the following code to evaluate after the page change

```
$(window).on("navigate", function (event, data) {
   alert('abc');
   event.stopImmediatePropagation();
   return false;
});
```

Comment: you cant override it, but you can run functions on back navigation.

Comment: there is no option to prevent this event?

Comment: You can do something like in this answer. http://stackoverflow.com/a/25808411/1771795

Comment: something with jquery mobile?

Comment: Yes, the answer works for JQM.

Comment: @Omar, actually I found what I wanted in pageContainer.